# Image decoration

Tags: php

How can we do image decoration in PHP, e.g. adding text or an image to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902000/how-can-i-overlay-a-watermark-on-an-already-resampled-image-in-php-using-gd  was posted 6 hours before you.

Answer (score 4):

With [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and/or [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) usually.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial can help: http://www.prodevtips.com/2009/09/10/image-manipulation-and-watermarking-in-php-with-gd2/